# Insert a node based on boolean value

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I have a XForm (in XSLTForms) where I have a checkbox (i.e. `xf:input` which has be binded to a `xs:boolean` type). Is it possible to (on submit) insert a node in my model based on the value of that checkbox?

To clarify, if I have the following model:

```
<xf:model>
    <xf:instance id="data">
        <data xmlns="">
            <element1/>
        </data>
    </xf:instance>
    <xf:instance id="helper">
        <data xmlns="">
            <bool1/>
        </data>
    </xf:instance>
    <xf:bind nodeset="instance('helper')/bool1" type="xs:boolean" />
</xf:model>
```

and this in my form:

```
<xf:input ref="instance('helper')/bool1" incremental="false">
    <xf:label>Some checkbox:</xf:label>
</xf:input>
```

I want to read the value of the checkbox and if it is true i need to insert a `element2` node in my `data` instance. If it is false nothing is inserted.
So if the checkbox is set I want to end with this:

```
<data xmlns="">
    <element1/>
    <element2/>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting `element2` before submitting, it would be easier to declare it relevant according to the node associated to the checkbox and to restrict the submission to relevant nodes.

-Alain

Comment: Thanks Alain, this is exactly what I needed. I am still learning about XForms so I am yet to discover all the tricks :)

Comment: Well, it's much more than a trick ;-) because it's a declarative approach instead of an algorithmic approach!